# I need help interpreting an expression

Tags: notation

I have the following formula:

> $$\min_{\beta_0,\beta}\sum_{i=1}^n[1-y_if(x_i)]_++\frac1{2C}\lVert \beta\rVert^2$$

What does the bracket with the subscripted plus mean?

I greatly appreciate your help. Thank you.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020/144766) to render math, rather than uploading an image.

Comment: Thank you for the advice. I was confused how to integrate LaTeX.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quite often, $x_+$ indicates $\max\{x,0\}$ and $x_-$ indicates $-\min\{x,0\}=(-x)_+$. Under these conventions $$\lvert x\rvert=x_++x_-\\ x=x_+-x_-$$

Comment: Thank you! @G. Sassatelli